# SSD is always running out of room

Tags: xfce, ssd, disk-usage, tmpfs

Today I opened my laptop to find the message: `Failed to write file '/home/chris/.cache/xfce4-notifyd-theme.rc.TF9RSX': write() failed: No space left on device` displayed on all workspaces. I googled the error code, but found nothing... First I ran `sudo apt-get autoclean` which made some space, but it was immediately filled. After running `df -h` this is my result:

```
chris@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       113G  107G     0 100% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  162M  1.4G  11% /run
tmpfs           3.9G  812K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           797M   20K  797M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Why is my hard drive constantly filling up if I don't download new files to occupy the disk space? Is it normal to have this much tmpfs bloat? Why do I have so many tmpfs? How can I fix this? I will run any commands if you need more information, thank you ahead of time.

Edit:
the result of `du --max-depth=2 -h` run in my home directory is:

```
56K ./chris/.xchat2
5.6M    ./chris/.eclipse
12K ./chris/.wireshark
96K ./chris/.java
12K ./chris/.dbus
175M    ./chris/.fgfs
4.0K    ./chris/.emacs.d
76K ./chris/.pulse
12K ./chris/.gnupg
4.0K    ./chris/.ssh
36K ./chris/.macromedia
776K    ./chris/.gstreamer-0.10
2.2G    ./chris/.git
55G ./chris/Videos
32K ./chris/.gnome2
12K ./chris/.oes
5.9M    ./chris/.config
129M    ./chris/Downloads
4.0K    ./chris/.gvfs
8.0K    ./chris/.cups
12M ./chris/.tor
64K ./chris/.FBReader
516K    ./chris/.gimp-2.8
36K ./chris/.redeclipse
12K ./chris/.audacity-data
3.4G    ./chris/Music
8.0K    ./chris/.mission-control
25M ./chris/.kde
20K ./chris/.supertux
14M ./chris/.adobe
8.0K    ./chris/.alsaplayer
427M    ./chris/.local
4.0K    ./chris/.gnome2_private
20G ./chris/Documents
du: cannot read directory ‘./chris/.rpmdb’: Permission denied
4.0K    ./chris/.rpmdb
772K    ./chris/.anki
651M    ./chris/Pictures
32K ./chris/.openshot
32M ./chris/.mozilla
8.0K    ./chris/.gvba
4.0K    ./chris/.wicd
4.0K    ./chris/Desktop
16K ./chris/.swt
280K    ./chris/.assaultcube_v1.104
8.0K    ./chris/.arduino
24K ./chris/.gnash
48K ./chris/.codeblocks
32K ./chris/.speech-dispatcher
12K ./chris/.vidalia
20K ./chris/.steam
746M    ./chris/.cache
104K    ./chris/.gconf
12K ./chris/.android
16K ./chris/.fontconfig
147M    ./chris/.minecraft
56M ./chris/.thumbnails
72K ./chris/.w3af
91G ./chris
91G .
```

and in /var it is:

```
4.0K    ./www/html
12K ./www
4.0K    ./games/asylum
24K ./games
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-private-5f5f77793aad4f2098e8f687ac922398-cups.service-xfobcd
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-colord.service-XHsgEEw
13M ./tmp/kdecache-chris
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-private-913d62fbb2204e0e99b13b7476c62fab-colord.service-NTCeKg
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-private-5f5f77793aad4f2098e8f687ac922398-rtkit-daemon.service-x67nDx
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-colord.service-XD4Uxbv
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-private-5f5f77793aad4f2098e8f687ac922398-colord.service-tTdyzv
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-rtkit-daemon.service-XKjazhE
4.0K    ./tmp/systemd-rtkit-daemon.service-XHWewtc
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-rtkit-daemon.service-Xk8cvl2
4.0K    ./tmp/audacity-chris
4.0K    ./tmp/systemd-colord.service-XAH1PfT
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-private-913d62fbb2204e0e99b13b7476c62fab-rtkit-daemon.service-4a3wEZ
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-rtkit-daemon.service-XWHDiow
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-private-913d62fbb2204e0e99b13b7476c62fab-cups.service-TUqDaa
8.0K    ./tmp/systemd-rtkit-daemon.service-Xr4rgUR
11M ./tmp/kdecache-kdm
23M ./tmp
4.0K    ./opt
4.0K    ./cache/gdm
1.1M    ./cache/nscd
488K    ./cache/samba
8.0K    ./cache/apache2
440K    ./cache/cracklib
124K    ./cache/ldconfig
36K ./cache/libvirt
8.5M    ./cache/debconf
4.0K    ./cache/fonts
72M ./cache/apt
4.0K    ./cache/pm-utils
2.8M    ./cache/man
152M    ./cache/apt-xapian-index
48K ./cache/dictionaries-common
1.5M    ./cache/fontconfig
7.0M    ./cache/flashplugin-nonfree
4.0K    ./cache/realmd
8.0K    ./cache/PackageKit
12M ./cache/cups
12K ./cache/bind
704K    ./cache/postgresql
8.0K    ./cache/analog
258M    ./cache
124K    ./log/samba
12K ./log/fsck
120K    ./log/apache2
25M ./log/condor
52K ./log/exim4
16K ./log/libvirt
540K    ./log/apt
4.0K    ./log/unattended-upgrades
4.0K    ./log/ntpstats
4.0K    ./log/firebird
36K ./log/ConsoleKit
416K    ./log/gdm3
16M ./log/installer
4.0K    ./log/chkrootkit
6.4M    ./log/boot-sav
4.0K    ./log/speech-dispatcher
96K ./log/cups
8.0K    ./log/hp
4.0K    ./log/news
76K ./log/postgresql
28K ./log/tor
2.0M    ./log/wicd
65M ./log
12K ./lib/sgml-base
3.6M    ./lib/aspell
16K ./lib/dovecot
8.0K    ./lib/xfonts
5.2M    ./lib/htdig
28K ./lib/pam
4.0K    ./lib/snmp
36K ./lib/openbox
2.3M    ./lib/samba
4.0K    ./lib/misc
29M ./lib/dkms
32K ./lib/NetworkManager
8.0K    ./lib/dbus
404K    ./lib/rkhunter
64K ./lib/ghostscript
4.0K    ./lib/initscripts
20K ./lib/colord
32K ./lib/apache2
3.2M    ./lib/ispell
4.0K    ./lib/container
4.0K    ./lib/rpm
12K ./lib/condor
332K    ./lib/systemd
16K ./lib/libreoffice
4.0K    ./lib/onioncat
16K ./lib/initramfs-tools
4.0K    ./lib/acpi-support
32K ./lib/exim4
24K ./lib/emacsen-common
4.0K    ./lib/udisks
4.0K    ./lib/insserv
8.0K    ./lib/logrotate
121M    ./lib/dpkg
40K ./lib/libvirt
16K ./lib/tex-common
12K ./lib/dhcp
4.0K    ./lib/update-rc.d
1.0M    ./lib/menu-xdg
4.0K    ./lib/os-prober
4.0K    ./lib/git
28K ./lib/gridengine
121M    ./lib/apt
4.0K    ./lib/ieee-data
1.5M    ./lib/firebird
8.0K    ./lib/ntp
8.0K    ./lib/urandom
5.8M    ./lib/gconf
320K    ./lib/ucf
104K    ./lib/gdm3
20K ./lib/AccountsService
28K ./lib/sudo
4.0K    ./lib/alien
3.4M    ./lib/apt-xapian-index
32K ./lib/dictionaries-common
8.0K    ./lib/xkb
4.0K    ./lib/geoclue
4.0K    ./lib/man-db
44K ./lib/texmf
32K ./lib/php5
4.0K    ./lib/avahi-autoipd
4.0K    ./lib/synaptic
8.0K    ./lib/flashplugin-nonfree
4.0K    ./lib/python
7.7M    ./lib/aptitude
4.0K    ./lib/realmd
8.0K    ./lib/vim
32K ./lib/upower
3.3M    ./lib/PackageKit
4.0K    ./lib/hp
496K    ./lib/usbutils
12K ./lib/sysv-rc-conf
20K ./lib/nfs
48K ./lib/polkit-1
9.1M    ./lib/mlocate
24K ./lib/libxml-sax-perl
8.0K    ./lib/bind
8.0K    ./lib/kdm
2.5M    ./lib/spamassassin
40K ./lib/xml-core
34M ./lib/postgresql
5.8M    ./lib/tor
28K ./lib/binfmts
8.0K    ./lib/security
16K ./lib/alsa
16K ./lib/wicd
4.0K    ./lib/usb_modeswitch
4.0K    ./lib/udisks2
360M    ./lib
4.0K    ./local
4.0K    ./cred_dir
15M ./backups
8.0K    ./spool/sa-exim
4.0K    ./spool/samba
20K ./spool/condor
12K ./spool/libreoffice
16K ./spool/exim4
11M ./spool/gridengine
6.0M    ./spool/torque
16K ./spool/anacron
4.0K    ./spool/rsyslog
4.1M    ./spool/cups
20K ./spool/cron
21M ./spool
2.4M    ./mail
742M    .
```

The only thing that stands out to me immediately is the 2.2G of git. I am certain that there cannot be that much there, but I really don't know how to use git, I just used it once for a tutorial.

Comment: You can use `du` to find what files are using your disk.  Start with your home directory, run `du --max-depth=2 -h`.  Then do the same in `/var` directory.

Comment: `du` stands for disk usage.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 91G is your filesystem and home. 90% of that is in your home directory. Your personal files.

2.2G ./chris/.git
55G ./chris/Videos
129M ./chris/Downloads
3.4G ./chris/Music
20G ./chris/Documents
651M ./chris/Pictures
746M ./chris/.cache

That is over 82G there. Literally half your drive is used up in /Videos.

Also, run:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And get "Disk Usage Analyzer."

Comment: I deleted some large video files only to find the empty space being encroached by ??? something... I ran autoclean and autoremove and nothing freed up (already ran them trying to free space before). Disk usage analyzer has shown that past kernel versions are in /lib... which is pretty much the only significant thing I could find.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "only to find the empty space being encroached by ??? something."     

Did you empty the trash bin after removing those videos? Your Documents folder is huge as well, talking almost a quarter of your space.     

Your .lib is 310M and 121M of that is in .lib/apt.      The two commands (rolled into one command) that I provided above should flush both old kernels and apt.

Answer (score 0):

On SSD disk you have to run fstrim regularly too. SSD works differently than old fashion hard disks. Take a look here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html.

Run fstrim on all your partitions. For instance:

```
sudo fstrim /
```

and make sure this is executed on a regular basis. Maybe a the start of a computer. Take a look also for information about optimizing Linux for SSD:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives
- https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization
- https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd
- etc.